# How to import global variable in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am new to Ember, and am trying to use a global variable in the config / environment file to then import it into several adapters and models. I need this to change the variable in one place, instead of editing each file.
In this case, the global variable is a string with the address of the api server. The variable is named **apiRoot**. I tried to use the following configuration, but it does not work. Please tell me what needs to be done, if this is possible in the Ember, or maybe there is another way? Thanks for any help!

Environment File:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(environment) {
  let ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'front',
    environment,
    rootURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
      },
      EXTEND_PROTOTYPES: {
        Date: false
      }
    },

    APP: {
    }
  };

  if (environment === 'development') {
  }

  if (environment === 'test') {
    ENV.locationType = 'none';
    ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
    ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;

    ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
    ENV.APP.autoboot = false;
  }

  if (environment === 'production') {
  }

  ENV.apiRoot = 'http://localhost:5555/api';

  return ENV;
};
```

Adapter:

```
import RESTAdapter from '@ember-data/adapter/rest';
import ENV from '../../config/environment';

export default RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: ENV.apiRoot,
  pathForType() {
    return "posts";
  }
});
```

Comment: This should work. Is the import path correct? You could try `import ENV from 'your-app-name/config/environment';`. Why do you think its not working? Can you verify if the imported `ENV` is `undefined`?

Comment: Oh, and when you change the `config/environment` you need to restart the ember server I believe

Comment: It’s strange. I thought that you just need to register the path to the file, but the ember requires the name of the project.

Comment: @Kiten Both is working. Allowing to have named imports from own package is an addition to the official resolution algorithm. I think your relative path is wrong. `config/environment` is relative to your `app` folder from node resolution perspective. It's confusing cause that's not how the file system layout is. So to import `config/environment` from `app/adapters/application.js` the relative import path is `../config/environment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your relative path probably refers to the `/config/environment` file *outside* of your `app`folder. But it should refer to `config/environment` inside your *app* folder, a file that *does not exist in your filesystem*!

The reason for that is that you are not importing the `config/environment` file from the file system. Because that file does not exist in the browser. Instead `ember-cli` will *execute* that file during *build time* and send only the resulting JSON to your browser an make it avaliable at `config/environment`. But for all path in the browser the *app* folder is the *root* of your project. You can not import something outside the `app` folder.

And so your `config/environment` JSON that `ember-cli` produced will be basically moved into the `app` folder.